# Логика Android-программы

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте.

Осваиваюсь в Android и Java. Хочется вынести часть логики программы из основного класса, дабы немного структурировать код. А по причине того, что необходимо наследовать интерфейсы, например, нажатия на элементе списка, а логика этого нажатия весьма длинная (для моей программы), получается не совсем "красиво", не так, как бы хотелось.
Создать класс - не проблема. Проблема возникает при создании нового Intent.

```
class FunctionItemClick implements OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Intent i = null;
        switch(arg2) {
        case 0:
            i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AdditionalActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, ActivityConstants.ACTIVITY_MFO);

            break;
            //... много строк кода еще
        }
    }
}
```

В результате чего получаем ошибку

> No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope.

Хотя класс MainActivity, импортирован в FunctionItemClick.java.

Как быть? Забыть об этой идее и делать все в основном классе или все же есть решение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема возникает из-за того, что Intent создается вне MainActivity. Чтобы заработало, нужно

1. либо внести класс FunctionItemClick внутрь MainActivity;
2. либо добавить ссылку в класс FunctionItemClick на экземпляр MainActivity, например, передав ее через конструктор, и использовать эту ссылку при создании Intent.

Comment: Собственно я сделал второй вариант, но "красота" и эффективность этого метода для меня сомнительны, вот и спрашиваю.

Comment: Это разумный подход. Правда, если использовать ссылку на экземпляр, нужно будет отслеживать ее валидность по перестроениям onSaveInstanceState и onRestoreInstanceState.

Comment: А можно подробнее? Для чего? Что может произойти?

Comment: Метод onRestoreInstanceState вызывается после метода onStart, когда активность переинициализируется из предварительно сохраненного состояния; после переинициализации предыдущая ссылка перестает указывать на новый экземпляр. Это все может быть существенно, если возможна ситуация, когда одна активность убивается, потом оживляется, а другая все еще живет.

Answer (score 0):

1. Вы прописали свою Activity в manifest?
2. Зачем вам вообще здесь Intent?

Если вы всё же уверены, что вам надо именно новую активность запускать, то посмотрите пример [Using Intent Demo](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/65.html).

PS: Сделайте этот класс лучше: дайте параметрам нормальные имена, а то что за такие arg1? И вынесите кейзы в switch в отдельные методы и назовите их как следует.

Comment: Как-то слишком язвительно.
Этот класс сделан для примера, именование переменнных в автосгенерированном методе Eclipse для данного вопроса не имеет смысла. 
2. Пример запуска нового Активити взят был со страницы разработчиков.
1. Мы не дошли еще по плану до добавления активити в манифест, ибо не все ошибки компиляции еще выловил.

P.S. Можно как-то прокомментировать удаление метки "android-sdk"?

Comment: Ссылка - ни о чем. Там создание простой активити, которая не возвращает никаких результатов. В моем же случае, использование startActivityForResult, обосновано тем, что "Активити 2" должна вернуть данные в "Активити 1". Для этого наследуется функция в "Активити 1" - onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent).

Comment: Я удалил android-sdk потому что метки android достаточно. Метка android-sdk имела бы смысл, если бы речь шла о проблеме с самим SDK, а здесь речь о платформе.

Comment: К сожалению, ответа все равно нет. О том, что стоит вынести логику switch-case в отдельную функцию - я и так знаю, проблема то не в этом, простите, я не просил учить меня, как писать программы.
Вопрос был в том, как это наиболее эффективно сделать, если вынести функцию в отдельный класс. Один из методов - передать в параметрах MainActivity.this, будет работать, но "красота" и эффективность этого метода для меня сомнительны, вот и спрашиваю.